# Does python have a session variable concept?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a datetime.date variable in python.I need to pass it to a function do operations according to the date given and then increment the date for the next set of operations.The problem is I have to do the operations in diff pages and hence I need the date as a variable which can go from page to page. Can we do this in python.......
This is to be done in .py scripts and not any web related work........

Comment: What have you tried so far? Some code, even non-working code, would help understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I cannot put up my code coz it is too long.I will try my best to explain you.I have a date variable.I have to pass it to a function in another.py page which will do some operations based on the date.After the operation is done it will increment date.Now the problem is I cannot return the Incremented Date.I cannot coz it is pgu.connect function.If I can I'm not aware.

Comment: Why not just use GET variables. Ex: page.py?date=20100508

Comment: You need to give more context in your question. The concept of "sessions" is not a Python concept. It probably means something in the context you are using Python in, but you never explained that.

Now I see that you say that you are not scripting web pages, so then I'm even more confused what you mean with sessoins. How are you running the .py scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python itself does not handle sessions. Sessions are a concept that is handled by the web server. For example Apache can handle sessions. Python can access the sessions variables with mod_python, mod_wsgi, or through cgi. Furthermore, web frameworks built on top of these technologies (ex: Django) can access session variables.

Answer (score 5):

Sessions have nothing to do with Python per se. See your web framework's documentation for how it handles sessions.

Answer (score 2):

You could build a global dict of "sessions" and update that dict when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a custom session solution, you may want to check out [this module](http://code.google.com/p/verse-quiz/source/browse/trunk/manager.py) used in a web-enabled Bible Verse quizzing program.